# 3D touch quick action crashes upon launch swift 3

Tags: ios, 3d, swift3, 3dtouch

I implemented 3D touch before making changes to my UI, which all i did was embedded my viewControllers into navigation controller. After those changes, my quick add 3D shortcut crashes the app every time i try to launch it using 3D touch. If I launch the app regularly, the app works just fine.

[Here is my main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmqYi.png)

Here is my appDelegate code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.krp.addEvent" {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addEventVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addEventVC") as! ViewController
        let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        root?.present(addEventVC, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in completionHandler(true)})
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the error in the debug console?

Comment: Weird, it doesn't give me error now but gives me this warning instead.. 2017-04-06 14:08:24.919742 Morning Star 2[23436:5882367] Warning: Attempt to present <Morning_Star_2.ViewController: 0x100b22890> on <UINavigationController: 0x10102a800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9